# Many hardware questions on IPMI usage - newbie

Tags: monitoring

I "inherited" two servers with Supermicro mothercard X8DTH-IF,version 1.0
I have no experience with IPMI and I didn't find useful info on the web for connectic point of view.

Note that the ipmi tag doesn't exist anymore (?) and I cannot create it :-(

Shall I install addon card ? I suppose no because a dedicated IPMI lan exists. Confirm please.

I would like to use IPMI from a local monitor pc and, in a second step also from a remote monitor pc:
- Shall I link all dedicated LAN ports to a switch and connect my local monitor pc on this switch ?

For the second step I see two solutions:
1) Shall I link all dedicated LAN ports to a switch-A and all LAN0 ports to another switch-B, then connect the switches to a router and use the remote monitor pc connected somewhere on internet ?

2) Finally, in order to simplify the cabling, shall I link all LAN1 ports to a switch and connect the switch to the router. In that case I must set the BIOS to use LAN1 also for IPMI.

Comment: Probably this question belongs to [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For local monitoring you are correct.

You could connect the dedicated IPMI ports to a 100Base-T switch and assign the IP addresses to the dedicated ports in the BIOS setup.

The idea to have IPMI accessible for remote monitoring has its disadvantages. First the web server and SSH server on IPMI are not very secure. You will need to use an additional firewall to secure remote access to the IPMI web server and the IMPI SSH sever.

Another option for remote monitoring would be to have a VPN access to the local monitoring network.

**Note:**
You can find more details on the set up and capabilities of SuperMicro IPMI in the [Supermicro Embedded BMC/IPMI User Guide](http://www.supermicro.com/manuals/other/Embedded_BMC_IPMI.pdf) that can be found on the Supermicro website.

Comment: Thank you. If I use the LAN1 for both internet access and IPMI monitoring, shall I set in the BIOS the same ip address ?

Comment: the IP address set up for the IPMI port should be different from the IP address of the OS interface. Internally there is an embedded 3-port switch behind LAN1 that connects the BMC, and the OS interface with LAN1.

Comment: therefore different but in the same segment: i.e 192.168.1.10 for the OS interface and 192.168.1.11 for IPMI